# Truncate "only" selected value from dropdown in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I wish the truncate the selected value of my dropdown in rails.

I am truncating like this at the moment like this. It is one of the `li` element of my `ul`.

```
<% @style.each do |ss| %>
      <li  role="presentation" class="testli" value="<%= ss.id %>"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"><%= ss.name + " - " + truncate(ss.description, length: 20, escape: false) %></a>
      </li>
<% end %>
```

What this is does is, It truncates the options of the dropdown as well.

```
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This CSS property isn't working for the dropdown although it works for a `<p>`

Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/6x039o7w/2/

Comment: I came across this, something like this only, but when I select the option 1, It should show the `....` but when I again open the dropdown those options shouldn't show the `...` . As it is the case here

Comment: this css solution may help you http://jsfiddle.net/8mTdM/

Comment: tried this already, doesn't work. Have put the same in the question

Comment: Try this in firefox as of now it will work. Will add ellipsis solution for chrome soon.

Comment: Bam, It works for FF.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by selected? Is this a class that's applied to a certain ss? or some state of `ss`?

If that's the case you could just do an if case like so

```
<% @style.each do |ss| %>
  <% if ss.selected %>
    <li  role="presentation" class="testli" value="<%= ss.id %>"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"><%= ss.name + " - " + truncate(ss.description, length: 20, escape: false) %></a>
    </li>
  <% else %>
     <li  role="presentation" class="testli" value="<%= ss.id %>"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"><%= ss.name + " - " + ss.description %></a>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE after first comment**
If you are dynamically selecting the option the best way to truncate is with javascript/jquery and not embedded ruby. You could do something along the lines of this:

```
$(".testli").on("click", function() {
  var myTruncatedString = $(this).text().substring(0,20);
  $(this).text(myTruncatedString)
})
```

Obviously not perfect but hopefully it brings the idea across.

Comment: with selected I mean, the option which I select from all the options

Comment: Update my post hope it helps!

Comment: It's not supposed to. I'm not sure exactly how you're doing things. It's just to help you get started.